# Xcode Issue "_main"

Tags: xcode

I have been stuck on this problem for awhile now. Countless hours and time and I still can't figure it out. Is there a solution to this problem that I have?

```
Ld /Users/alangibson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PumpkinMenace-ddpkivitawzujwdpdfyngakgkyxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PumpkinMenace.app/PumpkinMenace normal i386
    cd "/Users/alangibson/GameMaker-Studio/Pumpkin Menace/PumpkinMenace"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=5.1.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk -L/Users/alangibson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PumpkinMenace-ddpkivitawzujwdpdfyngakgkyxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L. -LFw -LPumpkinMenace -LFw/iOSSource -LPumpkinMenace/Game -LPumpkinMenace/Supporting\ Files -LFw/iOSSource/Source -LPumpkinMenace/Game/iOSSource -LPumpkinMenace/Supporting\ Files/__MACOSX -LPumpkinMenace/Supporting\ Files/games -LPumpkinMenace/Supporting\ Files/InAppSettings.bundle -LFw/iOSSource/Source/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.8.0 -LPumpkinMenace/Game/iOSSource/Source -LPumpkinMenace/Game/iOSSource/Source/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.8.0 -F/Users/alangibson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PumpkinMenace-ddpkivitawzujwdpdfyngakgkyxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/alangibson/GameMaker-Studio/Pumpkin\ Menace/PumpkinMenace/Fw -F/Users/alangibson/GameMaker-Studio/Pumpkin\ Menace/PumpkinMenace/PumpkinMenace/Supporting\ Files -filelist /Users/alangibson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PumpkinMenace-ddpkivitawzujwdpdfyngakgkyxs/Build/Intermediates/Pumpkin\ Menace.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PumpkinMenace.build/Objects-normal/i386/PumpkinMenace.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -objC -all_load -fobjc-arc -stdlib=libstdc++ -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=5.1.1 -liconv -framework CoreMedia -framework SystemConfiguration -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreData -framework CoreText -framework StoreKit -framework MapKit -framework AddressBookUI -framework CFNetwork -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -lsqlite3.0 -framework AddressBook -framework CoreLocation -framework MessageUI -framework MediaPlayer -framework AudioToolbox -framework GameKit -framework AVFoundation -lz -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenAL -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lFlurry -lyoyo_interpreted -framework GameController -framework FacebookSDK -framework AdSupport -framework iAd -lGoogleAdMobAds -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/alangibson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PumpkinMenace-ddpkivitawzujwdpdfyngakgkyxs/Build/Intermediates/Pumpkin\ Menace.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PumpkinMenace.build/Objects-normal/i386/PumpkinMenace_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/alangibson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PumpkinMenace-ddpkivitawzujwdpdfyngakgkyxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PumpkinMenace.app/PumpkinMenace
```

This is the Error

> ld: warning: ignoring file PumpkinMenace/Supporting Files/libyoyo_interpreted.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): PumpkinMenace/Supporting Files/libyoyo_interpreted.a
>       Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>         "_main", referenced from:
>            implicit entry/start for main executable
>       ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>       clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, every iPhone project has a "`main.m`" file (in Xcode 6.1, it's usually hiding in the "Supporting Files" folder of your project).

If you don't have that `main.m` file (which contains a `main` C-style function), that's why you are seeing the error you are seeing.

Here is what the main function looks like:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: So I would just add a new file to the supporting files then import that code? Also thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

> "Undefined symbols for architecture i386"

maybe the problem is in libyoyo_interpreted.a file because it was built for ios simulator architecture (i386), but you attempt to run application on device (which is arm7/armv7/arm64).

Rebuild libyoyo_interpreted.a for arm7/armv7 architectures. (it helped to me http://blog.diogot.com/blog/2013/09/18/static-libs-with-support-to-ios-5-and-arm64/)